# Add a fragment to a FragmentContainer android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, containers

I have an Activity with a bottom navigation view made of **fragments** which looks like this:

[image]

When I click on "Friends" fragment I would like to make something like that on the top of it, meaning to add another 2 fragments to this one :
[image]

For "Add friends" I want the layout of the "Friends" Fragment and for the other 2 ("Pending requests" and "Your Friends") I want a different layout which I'm gonna create.

My question is how can I do that? Is it possible to add a FragmentContainer to my "Friends" fragment and to add the 2 new fragments to it? I tried something but when I open "Pending requests" from "Add friends" tab the SearchBar is still there and it shouldn't be.

**Friends.xml** :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_friends"
    tools:context=".Fragments.UsersFragment"
    android:background="@color/purple_500">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addfriends"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Add friends" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pending"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Pending requests" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/yourfriends"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Your Friends" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:defaultQueryHint="Search Here"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_buttons"
   />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        >

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

In **.java** :

```
        Button Badd = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.addfriends);
        Button Bpending = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.pending);
        Button Bfriends = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.yourfriends);


        Badd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment friendsfragment = new FriendsFragment();

                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_friends, friendsfragment, "findThisFragment")
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
        });

        Bpending.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment pendingFragment = new PendingFragment();

                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_friends, pendingFragment, "findThisFragment")
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
        });

        Bfriends.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment yourFriendsFragment = new YourFriendsFragment();

                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_friends, yourFriendsFragment, "findThisFragment")
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
        });
```

Please help !

Comment: Your fragment container must contain no childs https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager

Comment: Can you be more specific for my case, please?

Comment: instead of using this use Viewpager with Mutliple fragment its help you to mange the data and also you dont have to mange home screen fragment and data make app code reliable and resuable

Comment: Yes but how to use it in a Fragment ? do you  have an example? I need to use the ViewPager in FRIENDS FRAGMENT.

Comment: @Daiana you can perform fragment transactions on containers containing no childs, For more info you should read android documentation.